# config cannot load custom environment variables - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, config, .env

My default.ts file is not able to load variables from custom-environment-variables.ts

```
// default.ts
export default
{
    accessTokenPrivateKey:"",
    refreshTokenPrivateKey:"",
};
```

```
// custom-environment-variables.ts file
export default
{
    accessTokenPrivateKey:"ACCESS_TOKEN_PRIVATE_KEY",
    accessTokenPublicKey:"ACCESS_TOKEN_PUBLIC_KEY",
    refreshTokenPrivateKey:"REFRESH_PRIVATE_KEY",
    refreshTokenPublicKey:"REFRESH_PUBLIC_KEY"
};
```

Another problem that I am facing is that custom-environment-variables.ts is not able to load values from env file
How do I make custom-environment-variables.ts override the values in default.ts please help

1. I have tried opening a new console
2. I have tried running Node in test environment still not working

Comment: Have you considered https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-var or alike ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and went through it for more than a week only to watch a Youtube Video on "James Q Quick's" channel where he shared a screen of the dotenv documentation. Their implementation of es6 is to use

```
import "dotenv/config"
```

instead of

```
import dotenv from "dotenv"
dotenv.config()
```

I'm answering 6 months after it was posted but having errors like this can make one question one's credibility